# Sibling model function in Qt5

Tags: qt5, siblings

We had the following code to retrieve data of type TYPE through a model, which is a custom proxy model. This is required by the next QSortFilterProxyModel to make the decision about filtering of elements. The code is actually combined from 2 functions: in the project we usually have some arbitrary index related to some ROW and use it to retrive the data from another predefined column which contains TYPE data.

```
QModelIndex index = sourceModel()->index(row, COLUMN1, sourceParent); /* sourceParent is always'invalid' - retrieving data from top-level items*/
ModelIndex sibling = index.sibling(row, COLUMN2);
return sibling.data(Qt::EditRole).value<TYPE>();
```

This worked fine with Qt4 but when moved to Qt5 sibling became 'invalid'. I wonder what has happened, taking into account that the data is actually there, which I see, by changing the code to the following

```
return sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, COLUMN2,    sourceParent).data(Qt::EditRole).value<TYPE>();
```

-works fine

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [implementation of sibling()](http://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/itemmodels/qsortfilterproxymodel.cpp.html#1900), I cannot tell what makes it return an invalid index in your case. Comparing with the [Qt4 implementation](http://code.woboq.org/kde/qt4/src/corelib/kernel/qabstractitemmodel.h.html#176), maybe it's around the `IndexMap` use.

But why don't you simply use your solution with `sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, COLUMN2, sourceParent)`, since it already seems to be what you actually want to do?